# Installing Ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded  Ubuntu 12.04.3 but how do I install it? I have attempted to open the download but nothing happens. I am currently running Fedora.

Comment: How did you install fedora?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. How about [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run it while your current OS is running. install it on a dvd or usb stick en reboot your computer with it.